# How to print more than one value in the same line?

Tags: carbon-lang

A simple example

```
Print("This is a number {0}", 1) // results in 4
```

How can I print `1 2 3` in the same line?

I have tried

```
Print(1, 2, 3) // Does not work
```

The forloop also does not work.

The while loop below prints the elements but each in a separate line since we do not have control over the `line feed` character `\n`:

```
fn Main() -> i32 {
    var a: [i32;3] = (1, 2, 3); // Define array containing the numbers 1,2,3
    var i:i32 =0;
    while(i<3){
        Print("{0}", a[i]);
        i= i+1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

which results in

```
  1
  2
  3
```

[here is the code](https://godbolt.org/z/EqKof384o)

How can I get `1 2 3`?

Comment: The documentation of Carbon lang is really scarce, but as a workaround, you can create a string and concatenate with the values 1, 2, 3, etc. and then print.

Comment: @Vallerious how do you collapse the array to string? I could not find that anywhere. And the for-loop is not working. Nor is the `Console.Print` function which should be able to do the same

Comment: Maybe wait until they write a doc. Sorry, but I tried to help with common knowledge that should work in any programming language. For example, we could create a string and concatenate the numbers with a space, then print the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short explanation**: Providing more than 2 arguments to `Print` is currently not supported, so is not including a line break.

**Details**

This is definitely something that will change in the future, as the language is in its early design phases. You can find the source for `Print` as an instrinsic (non-carbon native) here: https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang/blob/trunk/explorer/interpreter/type_checker.cpp#L2297

```cpp
        case IntrinsicExpression::Intrinsic::Print:
          // TODO: Remove Print special casing once we have variadics or
          // overloads. Here, that's the name Print instead of __intrinsic_print
          // in errors.
          if (args.size() < 1 || args.size() > 2) {
            return CompilationError(e->source_loc())
                   << "Print takes 1 or 2 arguments, received " << args.size();
          }
          CARBON_RETURN_IF_ERROR(ExpectExactType(
              e->source_loc(), "Print argument 0", arena_->New<StringType>(),
              &args[0]->static_type(), impl_scope));
          if (args.size() >= 2) {
            CARBON_RETURN_IF_ERROR(ExpectExactType(
                e->source_loc(), "Print argument 1", arena_->New<IntType>(),
                &args[1]->static_type(), impl_scope));
          }
```

If you look at the code you will also see that the type of input variable is limited to just integer types. It would be easy enough create a PR to manually add support for 2-3 if you want :)